# Number of Factors of 6

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

1. factor of 6 is 1,2,3,6, or
2. factor of 6 is 1,2,3,6,-1,-2,-3,-6

Which one is correct?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: There is unfortunately some ambiguity. The default assumption is ordinarily that we mean positive divisors. If we mean to include the negatives, ordinarily that is specified explicitly.

Comment: @FRM ; Who asked you this?  You used the (prime-factorization) tag,  and if you are trying to find the prime factorization, there's not reason to use negative factors.

Answer (score 1):

Which is correct depends on the context. If you are working with positive integers, the first answer would be correct. If you are working with integers the second is correct. If you are working with rational numbers neither is correct.

Quite often we look at the prime factorisation of some expression and say that it is unique up to multiplication by units. The units in the integers are $\pm 1$, hence the two points of view. Every non-zero rational is a unit, because the rationals form a field.

Comment: Since we have the two points of view, it is very frequent to assume that factors will be positive, and adjust by multiplying by a unit if necessary (where the idea of "positive" makes sense). Particularly when factorising positive integers this can be an assumed convention. However, when solving a quadratic by spotting the sum and product of the roots it is very important to be alert to the negative factors of the product - just to give a context where taking the positive factors won't do.

Answer (score 0):

We generally only consider positive factors, so the correct answer is (1).

Comment: Define “We”, please.

Comment: why??? 2*3=6 also -2*-3=6

Comment: What would be the factors of $-6$?

Comment: It's all a matter of context, but when somebody comes on to MSE asking to find the factors of $6$, the context is prettty clear. When factorization is taught to students first, it is generally done with natural numbers. So the goal is to find the factors when working with positive numbers.

Comment: Factorise $x^2+x-6$, $x^2-x-6$, $x^2+5x+6$, $x^2-5x+6$, $x^2+7x+6$, $x^2+5x-6$, $x^2-5x-6$, $x^2-7x+6$ - I agree that the context given by the question (limited though it is) suggests positive, but positivity doesn't generalise in the same way as primes and units.